# What is the "Replication" key for in a SQL Server connection string?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, database-replication, merge-replication

In a SQL Server connection string you can specify a boolean value for the `Replication` key, for example:

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Example;Integrated Security=True;Replication=True;
```

The closest I can find to documentation of this is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.replication?view=netframework-4.7#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnectionStringBuilder_Replication), which says:

> Gets or sets a Boolean value that indicates whether replication is supported using the connection.

But to me that doesn't really explain in enough detail what the setting actually does. Can someone give a deeper explanation of this?

I am working with databases that make use of replication, so it seems that this setting could be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly you should not be setting this property, even though the databases are parties in a replication topology.

Setting this property to true means that any constraint or trigger that is marked as `NOT FOR REPLICATION` will *not* be enforced for that connection.

The only time I'd consider using it is if you're actually implementing a new "replication-like" mechanism other than one of the built in ones and you're constructing a connection string for your replication agent.

`NOT FOR REPLICATION` itself is used where it is desirable that certain constraints are maintained from an application usage perspective but, due to the nature of replication (where, say, only a subset of data is being replicated) the constraint would be violated during the replication process.